# Show that $\dfrac{\sqrt{1+3x}-2}{\sqrt{x+8}-3} = \dfrac{3(\sqrt{x+8}+3)}{2+\sqrt{1+3x}}$ and hence find the limit as x tends to 1

Tags: limits

Show that $\dfrac{\sqrt{1+3x}-2}{\sqrt{x+8}-3} =  \dfrac{3(\sqrt{x+8}+3)}{2+\sqrt{1+3x}}$

I tried to rationalies the denominator but I got something like: $\dfrac{(\sqrt{1+3x}-2)(\sqrt{x+8}+3)}{x-1}$

Am I on the right track? I can't see how I get from there to what needs to be shown...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you're halfway there! Just apply the same trick by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the **numerator** this time; that is, multiply by:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1 + 3x} + 2}{\sqrt{1 + 3x} + 2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+3x}-2}{\sqrt{x+8}-3}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+3x}-2}{\sqrt{x+8}-3} \cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{1+3x}+2}{\sqrt{1+3x}+2} =\ldots $$

Answer (score 0):

Start from 
$$
\begin{array}{c}
3x-3 = 3(x-1) \\
1+3x - 4 = 3 (x+8 - 9)\\
(\sqrt{1+3x}+2)(\sqrt{1+3x}-2) = 3 (\sqrt{x+8} + 3)(\sqrt{x+8} -3)
\end{array}
$$
Now divide through by $(\sqrt{1+3x}+2)$, which cannot be zero:
$$
\sqrt{1+3x}-2 = 3 \frac{\sqrt{x+8} + 3}{\sqrt{1+3x}+2} (\sqrt{x+8} -3)
$$
Finally, assuming $x > -8$ and $x \neq 1$, divide through by $(\sqrt{x+8} -3)$ which is not zero:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1+3x}-2}{\sqrt{x+8} -3} = 3 \frac{\sqrt{x+8} + 3}{\sqrt{1+3x}+2} 
$$
which holds for all $x > -8$ such that $x \neq 1$.

Thus
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\sqrt{1+3x}-2}{\sqrt{x+8} -3} =
3 \frac{\sqrt{1+8} + 3}{\sqrt{1+3\cdot 1}+2} = 3 \frac{3 + 3}{2+2} = \frac{18}{4} = \frac{9}{2}
$$